# How to set content type?

Tags: json, scala, akka-http

I use akka http client 2.4.6 to post a json to server (server requires message's content type to be applicaton/json to handle):

```
val request = HttpRequest(uri = "http://localhost:9000/auth/add-user",
        method = HttpMethods.POST,
        entity = ByteString(write(createUser)))
        .withHeaders(headers.`Content-Type`(ContentTypes.`application/json`))
      Http().singleRequest(request)
```

And I receive this warning:

> Explicitly set HTTP header 'Content-Type: application/json' is
>   ignored, explicit `Content-Type` header is not allowed. Set
>   `HttpRequest.entity.contentType` instead.

and error on server side is:

> 415 Unsupported Media Type

How do I properly set content type for it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the predefined set of available `ContentType` definitions or make your own, and then pass that in when you set the data, but it has to be done through the `withEntity` method.

```
    // Making your own, from a string
    val c1 = ContentType(
     MediaType.custom(
      "my_custom_type",
      new MediaType.Encoding.Fixed(HttpCharsets.`UTF-8`))
    )
```

And then you pass this in to the request builder:

```
val req = HttpRequest(method = HttpMethods.POST, uri = Uri(url)
      .withQuery(..)
      .withHeaders(..)
      // notice how JSON content type is passed in here.
      .withEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, ByteString(write(createUser)))
```